# Calculations from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox

This is for an Acrobat order form we use at work to calculate the amount of paper needed to print jobs.  There are 4 conditions (saddle stitched books, perfect bound books single and double sided, and not books).  All use a different formula to calculate paper quantity.  I have all the formulas woking as individual programs but am having trouble getting them all together in the order form.  My original thought was to put them all into the output field as a long if else statement.  Then it occurred to me that I could run them from the checkbox.

Does either of these methods make more sense?

How do I run them from a checkbox and output the answer to field "PaperQty"?

This is the code for saddle stitched books.  I want this to run when SS_CB checkbox is checked and the result to show in "PaperQty" field.

```
// get field values; 
var FieldA = this.getField("Qty2").value;
var FieldB = this.getField("NoUp2").value;
var FieldC = this.getField("PageCount2").value;
event.value = ""; // default result; 
// test for non-zero divisor; 
if(Number(FieldB) != 0) {
event.value = (FieldC * FieldA / 4) / FieldB; // perform division;
event.value = Math.ceil(event.value); // Round up to next larger intiger;
}
```

Comment: Post your html code..

Comment: we need your html code. and by the awy do you use jquery or just javascript?

Comment: There is no html code this is just javascript for use in Adobe Acrobat custom script.